# Number not increasing during while loop: Division by zero, calculating factors of weather

Tags: python

I've been having quite a bit of trouble with some code I've been working on and I'm at the point now where I cannot figure out what is making it go wrong. The code in question is

```
brok = []
Jan = []
Feb = []
Mar = []
Apr = []
May = []
Jun = []
Jul = []
Aug = []
Sep = []
Oct = []
Nov = []
Dec = []
with open('CLLWeatherData.csv', 'r') as inputFile:
        for current_line in inputFile:
            brok.append(current_line.split(","))
            
maxe = 0
r=1
precip = 0
for r in range(1,len(brok)):
    if int(brok[r][4]) >= maxe:
        maxe = int(brok[r][4])
        
print("3-year maximum temperature:",maxe)
mine = maxe     

for r in range(1,len(brok)):
    if int(brok[r][4]) <= mine:
        mine = int(brok[r][4])
print("3-year minimum temperature:",mine)

for z in range (1, len(brok)):
    precip += float(brok[z][2])
    
avgperc = precip / len(brok)

print("3-year average precipitation:","{:.3f}".format(avgperc))
# print(brok[1][0][:2])
            
for I in range(len(brok)):
    if (brok[I][0][:2]) == "1/":
        Jan.append(brok[I])
    
    
    if (brok[I][0][:2]) == "2/":
        Feb.append(brok[I])
        

    if (brok[I][0][:2]) == "3/":
        Mar.append(brok[I])
    
    
    if (brok[I][0][:2]) == "4/":
        Apr.append(brok[I])
    
    
    if (brok[I][0][:2]) == "5/":
        May.append(brok[I])
    

    if (brok[I][0][:2]) == "6/":
        Jun.append(brok[I])
    
    
    if (brok[I][0][:2]) == "7/":
        Jul.append(brok[I])
    
    
    if (brok[I][0][:2]) == "8/":
        Aug.append(brok[I])
    

    if (brok[I][0][:2]) == "9/":
        Sep.append(brok[I])
    
    
    if (brok[I][0][:2]) == "10":
        Oct.append(brok[I])
    
    
    if (brok[I][0][:2]) == "11":
        Nov.append(brok[I])
    

    if (brok[I][0][:2]) == "12":
        Dec.append(brok[I])
    
# print(Oct[0][0][-4:])  
month = input("Please enter a month:")
date = int(input("Please enter a year:"))

numdays = 0

meantemp = 0.0

percentdaygood = 0.0
percentdaybad = 0.0
meanprecip = 0

munshort = month[0:3]

print("for",month,str(date) +":")
# print(month[0:3])

for I in range(len(munshort)):
    if munshort[I][0] == date :
        numdays += 1
        print(numdays)
        
for I in range(numdays):
     if int(munshort[I][0]) == date :
       
        meantemp += int(munshort[I][3])
        if int(munshort[I][1]) >= 10:
            percentdaygood += 1
        else: percentdaybad += 1
        meanprecip += float(munshort[I][2])

    
avgtemp = meantemp/numdays
(percentotal) = (percentdaygood/percentdaybad)*100
avgprecip = meanprecip/numdays

print("") 
print("Mean daily temperature:")
```

Currently the problem is within the counter for numdays, as I have no idea as to why it is not increasing inside of the loop, and it ends up erroring out the rest of my program with a divide by zero error.

[The data table that this code pulls from](https://files.catbox.moe/utgvzs.csv)

Answer (score 0):

#### Your code:-

```py
month = input("Please enter a month:")
munshort = month[0:3]
for I in range(len(munshort)):
    if munshort[I][0] == date :
        numdays += 1
        print(numdays)
```

---

#### Errors:-

- I suppose you are thinking `len(munshort)` gives the length of the list `Jan` if I input `'January'` but actually it gives the length of the string `'Jan'` which is 3.
- Because of the first error `munshort[0][0]` gives `'J'` and `'J'` is never equal to `date`.

---

#### Replacement:-

- You could try `month_list=globals()[f'{munshort}']` which returns the length of the list `Jan` or other months accordingly.

```py
month_list=globals()[f'{munshort}')
for dates in month_list:
    if dates[0] == date :
        numdays += 1
        print(numdays)
```

Comment: `for I in range(len(month_list)):` is needlessly noisy. Instead just write `for m in month_list:` There is no demonstrated need to know `I` in the code shown, but if there were, this can be achieved with `for i, m in enumerate(month_list):`